# Doesn't the applied torque in a frictionless environment continuously increase the angular velocity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum

Consider a sprinkle working in a no-friction universe (no air drag, no friction in the bearing). If this sprinkle ejects water with a constant flow rate, shouldn’t it be accelerating forever? A fluid-mechanics text book formulates this situation as follows:

In case of there is a retarding torque, $T_0$ at the center:

$$-T_0 = \dot{m}_\text{out}·(r·V_r).$$

$V_r$ is relative velocity between jet and nozzle where water is ejected and it is equal to $V_r = V_j - V_\text{nozzle}$ and therefore:

$$-T_0 = \dot{m}_\text{out} (r·V_{j}-r·V_\text{nozzle}).$$

Here $V_\text{nozzle} = ω·r$ then:
$$-T_0 = \dot{m}_\text{out}·(r·V_{j}-ω r^2)$$

Eventually:

$$ω = \frac{V_j}{r} - \frac{T_0}{\dot{m}_\text{out}·r^2}$$

The book says if $T_0 = 0$, the angular velocity would be equal to the jet velocity, which is constant. But intuitively I expect increasing angular velocity instead of a constant value. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what book you are referring to, but the above analysis seems to assume $V_j$ is already the jet speed relative to the nozzle. Either that or the interaction between the water and the sprinkler before the water is ejected is ignored, which isn't justified. In my answer below I assume $V_j$ is the relative speed, which makes $V_r$ the water speed relative to "ground".

Comment: @Puk $V_j$ is not relative velocity it is obtained by dividing volume flow rate of water to crossectional area of the nozzle outlet. I would like to add an additional statement from book which I forgot in original post; \textit{"The results may suprise you: Even if the retarding torque is negligible, the arm rotational speed is limited to value of $V_j/r$ imposed by outlet speed and the arm length."\emph{discoveries}

Comment: If $V_j$ is not the relative speed, then this is the quantity that should appear on the right hand side of your first equation, not $V_r$. Otherwise the torque applied on the water (and vice versa) as it travels along the sprinkler arms is neglected entirely. With the correct equations, you will find that the sprinkler should indeed keep accelerating, although constant water velocity relative to "ground" is perhaps not the most realistic assumption. Perhaps you should mention this book you are referring to.

Answer (score 3):

If $\omega = V_j/r$, then the tangential speed of the water with respect to the non-rotating "ground" frame is zero. In other words, the water coming out of the nozzle falls straight down, carrying zero angular momentum. This means the sprinkler imparts no net torque on the water, and likewise the water imparts no net torque on the sprinkler, causing the angular velocity of the sprinkler to remain constant.

Another way to think about this is as follows. Think of a small mass of water sucked into the sprinkler making its way outward in one of its arms. As this happens, the angular momentum of this mass increases, meaning the sprinkler is applying a tangential force (and hence a torque) on it in the spin direction. As the mass reaches the nozzle and is ejected, there is an instantaneous force (and torque) applied on it in the direction opposite to the spin. When $\omega = V_J/r$, these torques cancel out, so there is no net torque on either the water or the sprinkler.

Comment: Your comment comment about water imparts no net torque on the sprinkler when $ω = V_j/r$ does not make sense. The first formula in my original post uses $V_r$ which is relative velocity of jet with respect to nozzle of sprinkle. So, when sprinkle is rotating with $ω = V_j/r$ nozzle velocity will be $V_n = ω.r = V_j$  and relative velocity will be $V_r = 2. V_j$ and there will be net torque.

Comment: @CaptainCombo The equations and final result in your question are not consistent with $V_j$ being the water speed with respect to a non-rotating frame (or $V_r$ being the speed relative to the nozzle). If the water is always ejected at a non-zero velocity relative to "ground", the the sprinkler will keep accelerating in the absence of an opposing torque.